$\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\log(\cosh(y))^k e^{-(y-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} \mathrm{d}y$
Given $\mu \ge 0$, $\sigma > 0$, and $k \in \mathbb{N}$, I want to compute $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\log(\cosh(y)))^k e^{-(y-\mu)^2/2\sigma^2} \mathrm{d}y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\log(\cosh(\sigma x + \mu)))^k e^{- x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x.\tag{1}$$
A closed-form expression is too much to hope for, but there should be a better way to evaluate this than numerical integration!

Since $0 \le \log(\cosh(v)) \le |v|$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R}$, it is easy to show that the integral exists; in particular, $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty (\log(\cosh(\sigma x + \mu)))^k e^{- x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty |\sigma x + \mu|^k e^{- x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x \le (\sigma \sqrt{k} + \mu)^k. \tag{2}$$
A nontrivial fact is that there is an rapidly-converging series representation for the derivative of Equation 1 with respect to $\mu$ when $k=1$. That is,
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\mu} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \log(\cosh(\sigma x + \mu)) e^{-x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sinh(\sigma x + \mu)}{\cosh(\sigma x + \mu)} e^{-x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-(y-\mu-\sigma^2)^2/2-\mu+\sigma^2/2}-e^{-(y-\mu+\sigma^2)^2/2+\mu+\sigma^2/2}}{2\sigma\cosh(y)} \mathrm{d}y.\tag{3}$$
This integral can be split into two halves each of which is an instance of the Mordell integral:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-(y-\hat\mu)^2/2+\hat\mu-\sigma^2/2}}{2 \cosh(y)} \mathrm{d}y =  \frac12 + \frac{\sum_{n=1}^\infty e^{-2\sigma^2n^2} \sinh(2n(\hat\mu-\sigma^2)) \tanh(2n\sigma^2) + \frac{\pi}{2\sigma^2} e^{-(2n-1)^2\pi^2/8\sigma^2}\frac{\sin((2n-1)\pi(\hat\mu-\sigma^2)/2\sigma^2)}{\sinh((2n-1)\pi^2/4\sigma^2)}}{1 + 2 \sum_{m=1}^\infty e^{-2\sigma^2m^2} \cosh(2m(\hat\mu-\sigma^2))}.\tag{4}$$ Specifically setting $\hat\mu=\mu\pm\sigma^2$ in Equation 4 and substituting into Equation 3 gives a series representation that converges very rapidly, since the terms decay as $e^{-cn^2}$ for a constant $c>0$.
This gives me hope that there is a similar series representation for Equation 1 (i.e., without the derivative).
The obvious (to me) approaches to this problem don't work because $\cosh(\sqrt{-1}\pi/2)=\cos(\pi/2)=0$ and, thus, the function we are integrating has singularities at distance $\pi/2$ from $0$.
In particular, the Taylor series for $\log(\cosh(y))$ has a radius of convergence of $\pi/2$. The Taylor series can be found by integrating the Taylor series for $\tanh(y)$:
$$\log(\cosh(y)) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{4^n(4^n-1) B_{2n}}{(2n)! 2n} y^{2n},$$
where $B_{n}$ is $n^\text{th}$ Bernoulli number. Asymptotically, $\frac{4^n(4^n-1) B_{2n}}{(2n)! 2n} \approx \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\right)^{2n}$.

Slightly from a different perspective, how about returning to the expected value form of your integral and using methods such as Monter-Carlo to sample $E[f(N)]$ where $f(x)=log(cos(h))^k$? e.g. they list some methods here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3282643/numerical-evaluation-of-expectation.

You could get better luck on MSE.
